# Character input function through pointers is not yielding a response

Tags: arrays, c, ascii, newline

As part of a larger code repository, I replicated the gets() function by creating my own. The function merely accepts characters into a character array until it encounters a newline character or detects that the string length has been breached. The code is as follows:

```
void word_enter(char *word_search)
{
    char r;
    char *m=word_search;
    printf("Enter the word to search for: ");
    while((r==getchar())!=EOF)
    {
        if(r=='\n' || m==&word_search[WORD_LEN-1])
        {
            *m=0;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            *(m++)=r;
        }
    }
}
```

Apropos WORD_LEN, its value has been defined as 25 by the #define directive.

The function, however, doesn't work properly, and is rather jittery. Inputting a newline does not make the function cease, and the cursor merely shifts to the next line. What explains this? I've been bawling my hearts out figuring out as to what the error is, but to no avail. Be advised that while I'm awfully cognisant of the fact the string.h library has the same function under its belt, I intend to create mine from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing `r` with the return of `getchar()`:

```
while((r==getchar())!=EOF)
```

What you should do instead is to assign the return value of `getchar()` to `r`:

```
while((r=getchar())!=EOF)
```

Comment: How silly of me! Thanks, mate. Makes sense.